# Import Apache Cordova Build into Android Studio - Cannot find symbol class xxxx

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I've starting building apps with Phonegap / Apache Cordova, now using Cordova, and I would like to import the build into Android Studio for testing and to build the .apk.  It is all working good with the CLI for Cordova, and I can run the app in an emulator via the CLI with Cordova.  When I import into Android Studio (Mac OS X Yosemite, Studio version 1.1.0), it doesn't seem to import the entire directory structure and I am getting errors like "cannot find symbol class" CallbackContext, Config, CordovaArgs, etc.

I don't know if that is an issue with Cordova, Android Studio or some configuration error.  I haven't tried building with Phonegap and trying that instead.  I know that I can build an distribution .apk via the CLI, but that isn't as easy as with Android Studio.  I am running the latest version of Cordova, version 4.3.0.

I can provide more details if needed, just wondering if anyone has some suggestions.  I will build with phongap in the meantime if see if that works.

Thank you.

/sds

Comment: Seems to be some sort of issue with the Cordova Build.  If I build with PhoneGap I can import into Android Studio and just have to change a few settings to get it to build.  With the Cordova build, CordovaLib doesn't even show up in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be some sort of issue with the Cordova Build. If I build with PhoneGap I can import into Android Studio and just have to change a few settings to get it to build. With the Cordova build, CordovaLib doesn't even show up in Android Studio.